# iOS app closes immediately after changing bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode5.1

We are developing an iOS application. We need to change the bundle identifier, but if we change it and run the application on a real device, it's closes after 1 second without any messages, warnings, etc.

I deleted the old application before trying this.

- I tried changing it from `info.list` and it didn't solve the problem.
- I tried restarting the device and it didn't solve it, either.

Comment: Did you try to clean project Shift + CMD + K?

Comment: Did you do `clean` and `Clean Build Folder`?

Comment: There is almost certain an error in the console logs regarding the provisioning profile. Since XCode verifies the provisioning profile against your bundle identifier, it is likely that you simply need to do a clean build as others have suggested.

Comment: Is the bundle id in the provisioning profile? Maybe you have to create a new profile. I would also remove all profiles from the device (you can do so in the settings of the device).

Comment: it's not about provisioning profile. i tried to change it and not worked. if i change bundle identifier back, app works well. and there is even no profile with old bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. the application was an pointcloud.io application. at pointcloud.io i generated a new api key with my new bundle identifier and paste it in pointcloudapplication.cpp,  problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your App ID, Certificate and refresh your Provisioning Profile to match the new Bundle Identifier!

[image]

Comment: none of this worked. if i can change bundle identifier to back app keeps working. if i change bundle identifier again and app stops after 1 second

Comment: Have also you cleaned your project, deleted your DerivedData and refreshed the profile in the Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i fixed the issue once hope it helps

- Provisioning profile which you are using is not expired.
- Make sure that you have entered correct bundle identifier.
- Check the CSR in the key chain and make sure its not expired.
- Multiple CSR with same name if yes then delete anyone of them.
- Is the same profile working with other apps?

Don't forget to delete the derived data folder and clean your project before installing it in the real device.